# Log out of StackOverflow but it won't really

Tags: support, login, logout

If I am logged in on StackOverflow, and click "Log out", first of all, it shows some log in IDs info and a few more lines.

Under usual circumstances on most other websites, at this point I should be logged out already.  But StackOverflow won't.  It will require you to pinpoint yet another button "Log out" and then click it again, so that you are logged out.

AND, you are not really logged out.  If you come back to StackOverflow and click Log in, after 2, 3 seconds, it automatically logs you in, without asking for your password.

Maybe the "Log out Globally" can work something better.  But I wonder, if I am at Apple store or at a net cafe, how do I know I logged out but really didn't?  Somebody can come back to StackOverflow.com and log in automatically and do everything that I am allowed to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do not ask for confirmation on logout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/do-not-ask-for-confirmation-on-logout)

Comment: If your browser still have cookies for openid side (for eg google / gmail), it won't ask you password for Stack Overflow login, even you logout->login SO.

Comment: @Arjan - global login credentials are only applied after explicitly logging in using an OpenId.  Simply visiting a site doesn't restore them.

Comment: @Kevin, I stand corrected. I really thought I've seen different behavior, but even visiting my profile page on a site for which I still have a cookie, does not get me the Global Login local storage again. Deleted my confusing comment. (One minor thingy though: after "Log Out Everywhere" I now get redirected back to the home page which *looks* like I am still logged in. Hovering my user name, or browsing to some question, shows I am not really logged in though. Tested in both Chrome and Safari...)

Comment: Note that the log out page says *"If you are logged in to Meta Stack Overflow through multiple computers and wish to logout from them all, __or you are using a public computer__, click below"*. So [you need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86919/why/86922#86922) to use "Log out everywhere" to clear the [Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) HTML5 Local Storage too. That still will not clear the usual cookie for any other Stack Exchange site though. So, "Log out everywhere" from one SE site, will *not* log you out from all sites.

Comment: As an aside, in that Apple store: Safari will not clear HTML5 Local Storage when you remove the cookies. So: first use "Log out everywhere" to clear that, and after that clear all the cookies.

Comment: I failed to find the logout button, thus I'm hanging around here all night and day.

Comment: You could always go Incognito (cool name for a cool browser) or In-Private (boring name for a boring browser)...

Comment: @Cole IE is a browser? :P

Comment: @Doorknob I think, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cole I'm pretty sure that it's a Microsoft tool used for downloading Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Doorknob a tool, huh? Like [these swagglets](https://photos-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/971920_593158097398765_1495974449_n.png)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Heh :P But coincidentally, I have been commenting and answering from mobile this whole time (because I didn't have access to a computer), and just now I obtained access to a computer. It had IE. I downloaded Chrome, in about 5 minutes, and proceeded to close IE immediately :P

Comment: I always keep a copy on my [flash drive](http://PortableApps.com) so I don't have to even _use_ "IE" to install it on the desktop. I download Chrome from Chrome Portable, install Chrome, then close Chrome Portable and launch Chrome :)

Comment: Related: *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 3):

This made me not use SO in the beginning.

If you are using any OpenID to log in to stackoverflow then you need to log out of that openID separately. e.g. if you use yahoo then if you want to completely log out of SO then you need to firstly log out of yahoo mail and then log out of stackoverflow. That takes care of automatic login.

Comment: That's correct. This is not Stack Overflow's fault, it is a feature of OpenID. More discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/why-am-i-stilled-logged-into-gmail-and-stackoverflow-after-logging-out-of-stac).

Comment: @CodyGray It isn't Stackoverflow's fault but there is no simple explanation either. It isn't SO duty to tell people how to use OpenID but putting this in FAQ can be really helpful for new users. I wanted to use SO but didn't use it for at least one month. The only reason was that I couldn't find out how to log out of OpenID properly. Google search didn't help much. I accidentally found the way.

Comment: Correct, if I remove my cookies of openid.stackexchange.com then I have to enter my password, otherwise I don't have to. Thanks for your answer!