# Signing out of Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm working on implementing a login similar to Stackoverflow but what isn't clear to me is why it seems impossible to actually sign out of Stackoverflow after signing in. Is there some design philosophy why this should ever be done?

Comment: It's pretty easy to sign out of the main website, just go to the Stack Exchange dropdown and click the Log Out link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure you can log out

[image]

Comment: ...except [it's not really that simple.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/log-out-of-stackoverflow-but-it-wont-really)