# Propose Logout from Stack Exchange Sites Include Opportunity (with note) to Sign Out of OpenID.StackExchange or Other Credential

Tags: feature-request, openid, stack-exchange-openid, logout

When you request to logout, all the Stack Exchange sites that will be affected are listed and there is a note at the bottom

> If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID
>   provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.) as well.

but no explanation of how to do this is provided nor is a link to openid.stackexchange.com (or better the direct logout link).

There are dozens of questions about how to log out and expressing confusion about how OpenID works on Stack Exchange going back years (just glance at the linked and related headings on the right).  This excludes general discussion of OpenID and other standards.

The sometimes almost 4 year old links below are among the more relevant even though some of the details have changed.  Most of the "How do I logout?" questions or answers also apply.

Proposal 1. - Add an explicit link -- or better an option -- to also log out of OpenId for Stack Exchange.  Ideally this would only be present if that credential is currently valid.  More generally, the source of the credential actually used should be mentioned and an appropriate link provided.

Stack Exchange has changed (progressed!) several times.  In a sense, this proposal is the logical culmination of the current logout page.  An additional benefit is that it will also help train users in the correct way to use OpenID (or equivalent) specifically on Stack Exchange sites as well as more generally.

[Improve SE OpenID logout security and user experience on shared or public machines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119399/improve-se-openid-logout-security-and-user-experience-on-shared-or-public-machin)

[Stack Exchange OpenID credentials not removed on logout, allowing insecure re-login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118247/stack-exchange-openid-credentials-not-removed-on-logout-allowing-insecure-re-lo)

[Log out of StackOverflow but it won't really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/log-out-of-stackoverflow-but-it-wont-really)

[Is Stack Overflow having a logout bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289429/is-stack-overflow-having-a-logout-bug/289482)

Comment: We used to automatically log you out of Stack Exchange OpenID as well. I forget how/when that changed, gonna have to dig into file change history there.

Comment: Stack Exchange has changed, generally for the better.  This question address the Dec 2015 implementation.  I can see not automatically closing the SE OpenID as it may be used elsewhere.  Nevertheless, the logout page should offer the option for SE (or as much as possible if validated elsewhere) and a bit of guidance.   The SE login page also should not almost force the user to use OpenID (or other), but that is a different issue.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Huh... I just realized that [my feature request from yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924/tell-me-how-to-log-out-of-stack-exchange-openid) is an almost exact duplicate of this one.

Comment: Related: *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*