# Make my stackexchange.com "about me" the default for all my Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, profile-page

[Ilmari Karonen suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239633/1438):

> In fact, let me go a little bit further.  What I'd *really* want to have is a place (say, my network profile on stackexchange.com) where I can set up a *default* profile that automatically gets shown on all SE sites, *except* for those where I've customized it.

I'd like to slightly modify the suggestion:

- Profile edits on individual sites update the user's [stackexchange.com profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/1438) by default.
- Optionally, profiles may be [customized per site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson). (This does not touch stackexchange.com or any other site profile.)
- Site profiles that are [not customized per site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23504/jon-ericson) inherit the user's stackexchange.com profile.

[image: Profile editing flow chart]

A few caveats:

- I assume grandfathering in existing customizations is easy since the system seems to have noticed when I customized one of my profiles. If not, that would be a big monkey wrench.
- The "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button would need to be relabeled to "Save as network default". Maybe the "Save Profile" button too.
- There should be an option for profiles that have been customized to revert them to the stackexchange.com profile: a third button called "Revert to default".
- There would be no way to customize stackexchange.com, which is nothing new, but might limit options for future use of that space.

Comment: Currently the network profile inherits the profile (customizations and all) of your oldest non-Area-51 account.  That stinks.  There needs to be a way to customize it and make it the default, but I'm not sure how I feel about edits elsewhere pushing to it.  Seems like that could lead to errors; copying a profile update off of the site being edited should always involve explicit action on the user's part.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a way to lock profiles on certain sites to preserve them even if a "save and copy to all" was selected.

Comment: This behavior makes a lot of sense - I think the "SE.com" is a slight red herring. The idea here is that there's a "main" profile for each user that pushes to all but the exception cases.  The model is logical, but a lot harder to build an intuitive UI for. We actually built one that did it, but couldn't get to where its behavior was understandable to a user without needing detailed explanation of how things work.

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to *pull* the shared configuration to a particular site rather than push an overwrite everywhere, so that revert button sounds nice.  Pushing to all is a good way to accidentally nuke your custom profiles...