# Are 95-year-olds not allowed to use SE?

Tags: discussion, age

I tried setting my birthday to an old age to see if it would work, but I was stopped by a message that said "Birthday must be after 1920/01/01". According to [this article,](http://health.usnews.com/health-news/family-health/boomer-health/articles/2011/11/17/more-americans-living-to-90-us-census-finds) 1.9 million people in the U.S. lived to 90. This number has nearly tripled since 1980.

Shouldn't we have a more realistic age cap (hence *even more*), like 107?

Comment: And all the days of Methuselah were nine hundred sixty and nine years: and he died.

Comment: That error message says that only people older than 95 may specify their birthday :)

Comment: Thats just discrimination against people like me (I am 100 now).

Comment: "Birthday must be before 1920/01/01"... Doesn't that mean that the user has to be OLDER than 95 rather than younger?

Comment: @Dor He just made a mistake :)

Comment: Take a hike, grandpa.

Comment: @nicael Are you *really* 100 years old? o_O

Comment: It is quite a [known fact](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing/239626#239626) :)

Comment: @nicael I guess I'm kind of age-ist for not believing there could be a 100-year-old this active on a website community .-.