# Post score in the Top Network Posts borked somewhere

Tags: bug, profile-page

Noticed in [Jeff Atwood's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):

> [image]

[Actual score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches) is 320, shown 322. Also locked in 2013.

And then [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael):

> [image]

[First](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation/251097#251097) has a score of 179, shown 180. [Second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing/239626#239626) has a score of 123, shown 122.

Neither of these posts got any votes recently.

Comment: Still a pain to read, but you can figure it out at least.  I checked the timline for both posts and don't see any recent voting on your answers, so caching is not likely to blame.  And Jeff's answer obviously has not had any recent voting.  Did you have any serial voting reversals or delete user messages very recently?

Comment: @psub No, I didn't.

Comment: It seems to report the actual number of votes cast rather then the number cast - the number of votes lost from the removed users.

Comment: Same problem with the top network post of [this user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4144758/daniele-d) - displayed with a score of 10, while the actual score is 8.