# Main SE profile does not get updated automatically when profile information is updated on another SE site

Tags: bug, profile-page, stackexchange.com, network-profile, profile-sync

I recently discovered that if I go to, say, my Ask Ubuntu profile and I change the text for the about section for instance it will tell me that it has saved it across all SE sites, however even though it says this I have found that if I want it updated on my main SE profile then I have to go there and select which site I want to copy the information from.

But when I update my information on one SE site, unless I have specified otherwise, I expect the change to be done everywhere. So even if you do have some reasoning for not wanting it to automatically update on one's main profile I think that it should at least tell you about the fact that you have to go and do it there yourself (as the current text telling you it will update it across all SE sites is rather misleading), or perhaps provide a little check box to tick saying to update it there too.

**Information Update:**

Here is the requested screenshot:

[image: Save Profile button]

Comment: stackexchange.com is a portal, not a site.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I forgot that this button doesn't appear for everyone, but just for ones who has customized accounts (I seem to have got one, now the task is to figure where...). Either way, stackexchange.com is a different thing, not a q&a site, so it works differently. Up to the [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694), the network profile has been sync'ed with the oldest community profile, but only when you visited it (not entirely automatic), guess because it does just require different implementation.

---

stackexchange.com is not really a "Stack Exchange community", as the button in the profile editor says, so you have to update the profile info manually there.

> [image]

Also, there's no profile editor for your network profile, so you can't really edit it, but you can do it by updating based on some community profile.

Comment: But why? Is there a specific reason why it shouldn't update there?

Comment: I think that at least it should be made more clear there.

Comment: No, it's not, all it says is `Your profile will be updated everywhere. If you want, you can customize your profile just on this community.`, but it doesn't make it clear that `everywhere` doesn't include everywhere...

Comment: I only get a button that says `Save Profile`.

Comment: On some very rare occasions I have seen the buttons you show in your screenshot, however mostly what I see is the image I have added in my question.

Comment: Same there, same everywhere.

Comment: [New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing), see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TJnuD.png). /cc @ParanoidPanda (turns out OP didn't customise any profile yet.)

Comment: Similar situation with gravitar/photo, except the default is opposite, I.e., to not copy.  It gave me the option to copy to all, but the old still showed up.