# Old gravatar still appearing in my network profile after saving changes for all sites

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, profile-picture

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281553/what-can-should-be-done-if-anything-about-spam-addresses-to-my-stack-exchange), it was suggested that my default graphic was a security risk because it came from Gravatar, so I uploaded my high school photo (I was a lot better looking way back then).

The photo is appearing in some places where the old graphic used to, but other places still show the old graphic, and it is still served by gravatar.

If I click on my photo in the top bar to get the profile, and then click "View more" under the "Accounts" list, I get that list with the old graphic at the top.  I fixed it by selecting "update profile" and picking Meta as the source.

When I made the change yesterday, there was an option to apply it to all accounts.  Apparently, that didn't work.

Comment: Not a bug, stackexchange.com is not Q&A site hence it's not included when you update in all sites.

Comment: As Adam says in the other question: "If you want to update your profile on stackexchange.com after making changes on your Q&A site of choice, you'll need to repeat this process". (hence a dupe, since it explains the behavior.)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The other is about copying multiple items from one profile to *one* other.  I selected an option to copy one item (my just uploaded photo) to *all* profiles, and it didn't happen.

Comment: Like I said, stackexchange.com does not have a profile of its own. It's just a portal, with collection of all other profiles.

Comment: Anyway, found a better duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280171/main-se-profile-does-not-get-updated-automatically-when-profile-information-is-u (can't vote myself now, but I retracted my previous vote.)

Comment: Well, still not exactly the same but close.   And "all" should mean all, not "all except"