# Update Profile - Why does it only show 1 button sometimes?

Tags: support, design, profile-page

On the Edit Profile & Settings page, why does it only show the "Save Profile" button sometimes, while at other times, it shows 2 buttons?

> **2 buttons**
>
> [image: Image 1]
>
> Image Source: [Main SE profile does not get updated automatically when profile information is updated on another SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280171/main-se-profile-does-not-get-updated-automatically-when-profile-information-is-u/280172#280172)

---

> **1 button**
>
> [image: Image 2]
>
> Image Source: *(mine)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we know that the profile has not been customized anywhere, we will offer just the one button (with the line underneath, telling you that it will update everywhere).

If there has been customization, we offer the two buttons for ease of use.