# Change only 'Location' in my profile and apply to all communities while not changing 'About me' section

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile, location

I want to change the "Location" in my profile for all my Stack Exchange community sites, but I do not want to change the 'About me' section on each site.

If I choose 'Save change just for this community', it will change 'Location' for only one site. If I choose 'Save and copy changes to all public communities', it might copy the 'About me' section of the site to all other sites.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually, either changing your location in every place or saving that across all communities and reverting the unwanted About Me.

Comment: 10 years ago, the way it worked was, goto one profile somewhere and make some changes to however many fields and copy to all sites; only what you change gets copied network wide. Source: [New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619/282094) - if that's been revised, we'll need a link to the new implementation.

Comment: @Rob it seems it still works like this, so the OP doesn't need to worry about overwriting the About Me section.

Comment: @Marijn, if that's correct we should have 3 or 4 close duplicate votes on this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're two modes to save the changes when [editing your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current):

> [image]

For your particular case you can do the following steps:

1. Edit "location" **only** and save for **all** public communities. That will spread a new location (only field you have changed) to all your communities. All other non-modified fields will preserve their old values on all other sites.
2. *Only if needed.* Edit "about me" according your needs for current site and save for **this** community only.

Comment: and what if you already have changes to your about me that are different than other sites that you don't want to apply to all other sites?

Comment: @starball it's easy to copy it to clipboard or other text editor, revert changes and next do what I suggested in the post. Not an issue at all.

Comment: I think the situation that prompted this question is a user that has customized the About Me on all their sites, for example on SO the About Me is "I like programming", on Money.SE they put "I like money", on Academia.SE it is "I like studying" etc., and they don't want to redo/copy paste all of those when only changing the location.

Comment: @Marijn that's exactly what can will be achieved on step 1 from my answer. If they need to update only location, just modify only location (on any profile) and press "Save and copy **CHANGES** to all public communities". All the rest fields will be intact.

Comment: The answer was a bit unclear at first, but it now solves my concern after editing. If I change only the 'Location' field and do not change the 'About me' section, and then click 'Save and copy changes to all public communities', then it changes only the 'Location' field.

Comment: @user67275 I agree, the wording could be made more clear. Like, what is the scope of "changes"? Instead of "*changes*", something like "*modified fields*" would have spared me some confusion and fret.